# C# Unable to determine the principal end of the relationship

Tags: c#, entity-framework

```
foreach (var item in order.MyFiles)
{
   var newFile = adapter.db.File.CreateObject();

   newFile.Name = item.FileName;

   adapter.db.File.AddObject(newFile);

   adapter.db.SaveChanges();

   item.MyFile.Add(new MyFile { FileID = newFile.FileID });

   adapter.db.SaveChanges();
}

foreach (var item in tempFilesList)
{
    adapter.db.DeleteObject(item);
}

adapter.db.SaveChanges();
```

That code duplicates rows in the `MyFile` table, e.g if the loop iterates 3 times I see 6 rows (3 x 2*`adapter.db.SaveChanges()` ???)

But, if I just have only one `adapter.db.SaveChanges();` (that last one) I get the error

**Unable to determine the principal end of the 'my_dbModel.FK_MyFile_File' relationship. Multiple added entities may have the same primary key.**

I suppose it is caused that in that case it doesn't commit the `adapter.db.File.AddObject(newFile);` items before assinging them to the `item.MyFile.Add(new MyFile { FileID = newFile.FileID });` But I can be wrong, any ideas how to fix it?

Answer (score 55, accepted):

You cannot use `newFile.FileID` when defining a new `MyFile` before saving changes. The FileID is default (0) until you save the new entity in database. You'd have to use navigation property of `File` in your `MyFile` class. EF will detect the relation and will commit data appropriately.

Try to change the line `item.MyFile.Add(new MyFile { FileID = newFile.FileID });` with:

```
item.MyFile.Add(new MyFile { File = newFile });
```

where `File` is the navigation property defined in `MyFile` entity.

Answer (score 2):

This could be because of a cyclic reference in you EDMX back to the same table.

Means for example if EmployeeDepartment is the table that you are going to update and the Primary key is EmployeeDepartmentID and if it is identity column and auto-generated, Check in the EDMX whether the  EmployeeDepartmentID is referenced back to itself. If so, right click on that foreigh key reference and click delete.

This worked for me and I hope this works for you as well.

Thanks,

Bibin.

Comment: So youre saying DONT include the self reference?

Comment: You don't have to delete the reference, if the recursive or cyclic reference is part of your schema, then keep it in. Just make sure it is optional, not required (nullable) then it is a perfectly valid structure. This answer is suggesting that you compromise the integrity of your data.